# Is there an IOS app that mimics "while you were out phone message pads"

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

but txt all the info to multiple recepients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Notes app does this perfectly on iOS 11.

Take a picture of the paper, crop and color correct if you please. *You can also or store in iCloud Drive, photos or store on the iPad as a file, but I kind of like the notes app.*

Then annotate the image with text typing, finger drawing in pen, pencil, marker or use a stylus or Apple Pencil on iPad.

Then send the file using messages or any other app.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of template based notes..and less taking picture, crop, and annotate...

Comment: Yup @cubenam. But with markup being good enough, most people are going to be making AR rulers which are the new flashlight apps for this release. I bet there’s a messages sticker that puts these stamps in, though. But without the template part.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old but since today there is a new answer possible. ProjectWizards has released an iPhone and iPad app especially for sending out WYWO notes. I think the is/was what you asked for: https://www.projectwizards.net/en/phone-memo

Comment: Important note which I almost forgot to mention: I am affiliated with the product. If this kind of an answer is not allowed, please tell me and i will pull back my answer.